# Python - Issues with Scapy send function

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy

How can I make it so 2 of these functions work with loop=1? For some reason if loop is = to 1 it won't do anything else but send, so my timer stops counting down, and it won't do time.sleep(3) each time it sends either how can I make these functions work with loop = 1

```
import time
import threading
from scapy.all import *

try:
    ip = raw_input("IP Address: ")

    timeout = time.time() + 1 * 12

    def sendicmp():
        try:
            while True:
                if time.time() > timeout:
                    break
                packet = IP(dst=ip)/ICMP()
                send(fragment(packet), loop=1, verbose=0)
                time.sleep(3)
        except:
            pass

    for i in range(1):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=sendicmp)
        thread.start()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Hmmmm the `loop=1` basically means “repeat indefinitely the sending”.

Comment: i know it does.

Comment: Meaning that it will never stop until you ^C, which you can’t do because it’s in a thread :/ so your code will be stuck... what even is your problem then ?

Comment: I already told you... Time.sleep(3) doesn't work and the timer doesn't either because if it constantly sends my timer won't kill the script if it is running

Comment: It is normal that send with loop=1 never ends ! You need to find another way

Comment: which is literally what this post is for XD

Comment: Ok now we are set. Then remove `loop=1` and your code will work. You already have the loop to send lots of packet

Comment: if I removed time.sleep the amount wouldn't be anywhere near if I kept loop=1 lawl